# Django is not sending mail

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

We have a Django application that runs on CentOS.
We've created a new feature for password reset using the Django auth and forms.

This works when working on development servers but when I deploy this to our production environment the mail with the unique link is not being sent.
I've pinpointed the problem to the fact that Django using smtplib is trying to send the e-mail through port 25 with Postfix instead using the settings.py which is pointed to Google server.

When i turn Postfix off I get connection refused when trying to reset the password.

We have other mail functionality that works, only the reset password doesn't.

My settings.py:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my-mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'my-pass'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'my-mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'my-mail@gmail.com'
```

The view is from auth_views.password_reset and I'm calling it from my main urls.py file.

Solution:
It turns out I had another settings.py file located in the home directory of the project as backup.
The problem was I added this home directory in the apache/django.wsgi file so Django was looking at this file and not the updated.
Once I've deleted this file everything works.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If other mail functionality is working, the error is most probably hiding in your view. So if you post it, we could try to help

Comment: I've edited my question to reflect your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: It turns out I had another settings.py file located in the home directory of the project as backup. The problem was I added this home directory in the apache/django.wsgi file so Django was looking at this file and not the updated. Once I've deleted this file everything works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have simply set following setting:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'myemailpwd'
```

And, following code send emails without any interruption

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage('TEST TITLE', 'TEST BODY', to=[email])
email.send()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can send mails through the shell but not with Django. I'm not saying it's a problem with Django but I can't see what can cause this on my server. Might be something to do with Auth/views.py or forms.py

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and write error you are getting if any.

In settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

In send_mail.py

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
import settings

def send_mail():
 from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
 to_email = ['your_email_address@example.com']
 subject = "Any text"
 body = "Hello world"
 msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, body, from_email, to_email)
 msg.send()

send_mail()
```

Comment: Hi, this will work and I can send mails with this code. The problem is when I try to use the PasswordResetForm function.